# Direction of Bias in OLS with systematic measurement error

Tags: least-squares, bias, measurement-error

I am looking at a study that wants to measure the effect of $x_t$ on $Y_t$, but the true values of the $x_t$ are not observed. Instead, what is observed is a minimum value for $x_t$. In effect, what the study is saying is that, the independent variable is "at least X".

I am familiar with the fact that if I introduce random measurement error into the $x_t$ terms, I will be biased toward finding no result in the hypothesis test (cannot reject null). But what if the measurement error is not random, ie. $X^*_t = x_t + \nu$, where $\nu \ge 0$? How can I know (or can I) the direction of the bias in $\beta$?

Comment: Is this really _measurement error_, or rather a _censored_ regressor in the sense of [Rigobon & Stoker](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4542020)?